# When do you use entities, value objects and aggregates (DDD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I read the book on Domain Driven Design (DDD) by Eric Evans. He wrote a chapter on building blocks of DDD: entities, value objects and aggregates. How you define these building blocks using identities for entities, unique items for value objects, etc. It seems like quite some work to me.

So far I only found some brief explanations on **how** it works, but not on **why** you should programm this way.

So my questions are: why should you structure your code this way? Why should you use entities, value objects, etc. as building blocks for your code? What is the advantage and when is it worth the effort?

Comment: As a side note, the Evans book is not generally a great resource to start DDD with.  Vernon's books are generally better.  The level of work required to structure things this way is also somewhat dependent on technology choices.

Answer (score 1):

##### Entity versus Value object

In DDD, you model your business cases using domain objects. These objects can fall into 2 categories: entities and value objects. Entites have a natural key to identify them, wheras value objects are solely identified by their value.

For instance, in my country, the department of justice considers that the identity of a person is a composition between the following informations:  birth sex, birth name, birth city, birth date, first names. Social security, on the other hand, assign a unique number to each person, which operates as a natural key (1 person = 1 SSN). If both business had to do domain modeling, the DoJ would use a value object, whereas the social secuity would use an entity.

##### Aggregates versus Entity

DDD is used to model complex business rules and interactions in a domain layer. This domain layer is integrated into applications in order to ensure that state changing use cases (called commands) do not violate these invariants. When handling a command, the application rehydrates the current domain state from the persistence store (via a repository), then apply the requested change on the model, ensures it does not violate the constraints (or alter the change to respect them), and then send the new valid domain state to the infrastructure for persistence.

Commands can target either a specific single object or a complex structure. For instance, a person can have an address ; addresses can be either modeled using a single scalar value in the Person class (a string containing the formatted address) or an object with multiple properties (number, street, city), which may have sub-objects (city can be structured with zip, name, etc ...).

Commands cannot target only a value object, because there is no identity in these objects so you can't reference them atomically. They are only a mean to structure informations in order to apply business rules within an entity. So commands can either target a single entity or a structure of multiple objects, amongts which at least one is an entity. Such a structure is called an aggregate, and the whole structure is referred to by the identifier of one of the entities called the aggregate root.

##### Why aggregates

While theorically it is possible to model all your domain using exclusively entities rather than aggregates (with only scalar values), this can make your domain layer code a bit complicated and add some duplications.

If Person entity only have a scalar address value, you can't manipulate subconcepts such as zip codes or cities, or that would require some parsing which could not be application independant. Following DDD principles, you shall rather have a structure of data in the domain layer and require non-domain layers, which are application-dependant, to do the parsing for you. this way you separate business concerns (city XXX is in country YYY) from technical concerns (address format using RFC ZZZ).

You could also split the value into multiple scalar values such as addressNumber, addressStreetName, addressCity, addressZip, but it is advantageous to regroup address data into an address value object. It easiens the navigation, and also allows reusing the concept and busines rules applying to it. For instance, you could have a geolocator service that helps you validating city name, zip code and coutry. By separating this concern from the person entity, you can reuse the same structure and business rules in the order entity.

---

##### Appendix 1: When to use DDD

DDD is best used when you have the following context:

- **Writing multiple application with the same business contraints and capable of sharing units of code** (probably the most underlook condition for DDD to be valuable)
- Enough infrastructure, management, domain expertise, and development force to maintain a quality domain layer unit of code independantly from apps using them
- Knowledge on how to maintain an external unit of code that can be reused by developpers of multiple applications (both technically and at management level)

However, if you're maintaining a simple application that does not enter a pure DDD approach (with an externally maintained domain layer), it is good practice to think how you can develop with at least some sort of infrastructure independence at certain levels, so you don't need to scratch it everytime an infrastructure constraints comes into scope.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ArwynFr notes, DDD intends to reduce the complexity of hard domains. To do that, it uses the divide and conquer concept. It divides the large complex domain into smaller building blocks to increase each block's coherency and decrease the coupling between them, which are signs of good design in software. But why were these blocks introduced?

- **Aggregate** represents the consistency of related entities that must be kept at all times.
- **Entity** represents the identifiable and trackable piece of data that belongs to an Aggregate. It has actions that have business invariants and
  logic behind them.
- **AggregateRoot** is an *Entity* that represents the entry point that ensures the consistency of the aggregate.
- **ValueObject** represents a piece of data that isn't identifiable or trackable but it has actions that have business invariants and logic behind them. It was introduced because it enables reusability, SRP, and readability. It also makes your design flexible and easier to manage.

> What is the advantage and when is it worth the effort?

Well, in all DDD books, you can find this: When you have a complex domain it's worth it. But how do you measure the complexity of a domain? Well, to measure it precisely you need software analysis measurements. There are many articles and research about that. But in general, if you have a domain whose needs are *changing frequently* or the business logic behind every entity is *dependent on each other* and it's *beyond CRUD-based logic*, you can call it complex. (not so accurate but it draws a picture).

The advantage is the good design: **low coupling and high cohesion**. Your design will be *flexible* enough to accept frequent changes. It makes it easier to reason about the features and requirements. Makes it easy to write *unit tests*. Your domain model reflects the stakeholder's needs. No need to read other layers' code. By reading the domain layer code only, you understand the *business capabilities* behind the software.